# Question about Girsanov and Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

could you please help me to prove the following :

$$ E^*\left[X|F_t\right]=\frac{E\left[X\frac{dP^*}{dP}|F_t \right]}{\rho_t} $$

Given that $\rho_t $ a martingale

$$ \rho_t=\frac{dP^*}{dP}|F_t$$

This is what I’ve done, but no success. I think there’s something wrong with my understanding :

$$ \frac{E\left[X\frac{dP^*}{dP}|F_t \right]}{\rho_t} =\frac{E\left[X\rho_t|F_t\right] }{\rho_t}   $$
$$=\frac{\rho_t E\left[X |F_t \right]}{\rho_t} $$
$$=E[X |F_t ]\neq E^*[ X |F_t] $$

Comment: Mistake: The numerator is $E\left[Y\mid F_t \right]$ with $Y=X\frac{dP^*}{dP}$, not $Y=X\rho_t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
\rho_t = E\left(\frac{dP^*}{dP}\mid\mathcal{F}_t \right),
\end{align*}
instead of 
\begin{align*}
\rho_t = \frac{dP^*}{dP}\big| \mathcal{F}_t.
\end{align*}
Then, for any $C \in \mathcal{F}_t$,
\begin{align*}
\int_C E\left(X \frac{dP^*}{dP}\mid\mathcal{F}_t \right) dP &=\int_C X \frac{dP^*}{dP} dP\\
&=\int_C X dP^*\\
&=\int_C E^*(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t) dP^*\\
&=\int_C E^*(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t) \frac{dP^*}{dP} dP\\
&=\int_C E\left(E^*(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t) \frac{dP^*}{dP} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)dP\\
&=\int_C E^*(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t)E\left(\frac{dP^*}{dP} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right)dP\\
&=\int_C E^*(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t) \rho_t\, dP.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
E\left(X \frac{dP^*}{dP}\mid\mathcal{F}_t \right) = E^*(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t) \rho_t,
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
E^*(X\mid \mathcal{F}_t) = \frac{E\left(X \frac{dP^*}{dP}\mid\mathcal{F}_t \right)}{\rho_t}.
\end{align*}